# Display an array in a NSTextView in a NSScrollView object

Tags: objective-c, arrays, string, nstextview

How would I display an array in a `NSTextView` in a `NSScrollView` Object in `Xcode`?

For example, just having a simple array of strings like this:

```
NSMutableArray *thisArrary = [NSMutableArrary new];
[thisArrary addObject:@"String 0\n"];
[thisArrary addObject:@"String 1\n"];
[thisArrary addObject:@"String 2\n"];
```

And then be able to display the whole array in the NSTextView.

Would it be easier if I used a string and then added to it each time, and then displayed that in the `NSTextView`? For example:

```
NSString *thisString = @"String 0\n";
thisString = [NSString stringWithFormat @"%@String 1\n", thisString];
thisString = [NSString stringWithFormat @"%@String 2\n", thisString];
```

Comment: You should learn how to use scrollview and textview, Check this [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/TextUILayer/Tasks/TextInScrollView.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *strings = @[@"String 0", @"String 1", @"String 2"];
NSString *combinedString = [strings componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
textView.string = combinedString;
```